# Integrating Azure platform with other cloud providers

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, azureservicebus, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to integrate my azure solution with different cloud providers. I need to pull data from different cloud providers. They will expose the data via Rest services. I need to pull the data and publish it to my Azure platform. I am thinking of using the Azure Service Bus to pull the data and publish to an Azure Event Hub. Do you think this is better approach or any other good way to connect to a different cloud from Azure.

Answer (score 1):

If the cloud providers you're trying to integrate with made data available via a RESTful API, I don't think Service Bus is going to help you. To make use of Service Bus, the third party cloud providers would need to enqueue data to a Service Bus Queue or Topic.

If you're trying to consume data periodically from RESTful APIs, how about using an Azure WebJob that calls those third party RESTful APIs on an interval, then processes the data?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/ This service will not help?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstand what you're trying to do. Let's say the third party service you're accessing has an API endpoint of https://www.foobar.com/some-web-method, and this service returns JSON data. For Service Bus to be of help, you'd have to first call the web service, parse the results, then add a message containing the data to a Service Bus queue. Or you'd have to have foobar.com enqueue messages for you. So if I understand your problem correctly, it will not help communicate with third party RESTful APIs.